# Как работать со строкой в C#, получаемый через WebRequests?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Как работать со строкой в C#, получаемый через `WebRequests`?

если кому интересно что такое класс [WebRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class)

в приложении ответ хранится в `responseFromServer`

выглядит он так
`age=1000&name=sasha`

Как присвоить переменным в приложении значения age и name?

(хотя это и не является параметрами так как это просто текст `age=1000&name=sasha` )

в итоге нужно чтобы переменные в C# получили значения пример:
`age = 1000; name = sasha;`

Может есть какая-нибудь функция которая распарсит как надо строку как в php делает parse_str

Comment: Ну C# и PHP отличаются, поэтому есть парсер в коллекцию [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpUtility_ParseQueryString_System_String_)

Comment: Вообще-то все уже существует смотрите в сторону `Request.QueryString["age"].ToString()`

Comment: @AlexKrass @Monomax спасибо, но к сожаления не понял как внедрить ```ParseQueryString```.Кажется в ```ParseQueryString``` нужно создавать новый запрос на отправку запроса серверу. К сожаление это значит что пришлось бы заменить ```WebRequests``` Так как у меня всего 5 значений и нет вложенности. Использовал ```string[] arr = { responseFromServer }; // где responseFromServer = "1000", "sasha", "Three", "Four", "Five"
                    string age = arr.ElementAt(0);
                    string name = arr.ElementAt(1);```

Comment: @Bald хочу чтобы вы тоже посмотрели, если интересно. Ваш ответ тоже был полезен, спасибо.